# Some git colors don't work in powershell. Why?

Tags: powershell, git, cmd.exe

I set my git console color for changed files to yellow.  This works in `cmd.exe`, but not powershell.  However, *some* colors work, and others appear to map to completely other colors.  Magenta is rendered as blue in powershell.  How did this crazy state of affairs come to be, and how can I make it work as expected?

[image: shell color comparison]

Answer (score 5):

The cmd console's colors are defined via colortable entries
(24 bit, 8bit colors RGB reversed 0xBBGGRR),
which can be viewed in the registry:

```
> reg query "hkcu\console"

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\console
    ColorTable00    REG_DWORD    0x0
    ColorTable01    REG_DWORD    0x800000
    ColorTable02    REG_DWORD    0x8000
    ColorTable03    REG_DWORD    0x808000
    ColorTable04    REG_DWORD    0x80
    ColorTable05    REG_DWORD    0x800080
    ColorTable06    REG_DWORD    0x8080
    ColorTable07    REG_DWORD    0xc0c0c0
    ColorTable08    REG_DWORD    0x808080
    ColorTable09    REG_DWORD    0xff0000
    ColorTable10    REG_DWORD    0xff00
    ColorTable11    REG_DWORD    0xffff00
    ColorTable12    REG_DWORD    0xff
    ColorTable13    REG_DWORD    0xff00ff
    ColorTable14    REG_DWORD    0xffff
    ColorTable15    REG_DWORD    0xffffff
```

The cmd `color /?` naming deviates from [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20588680/6811411)

```
Color /?         Dec Hex PowerShell 
0 = Black          0  0  Black  
1 = Blue           1  1  DarkBlue  
2 = Green          2  2  DarkGreen  
3 = Aqua           3  3  DarkCyan  
4 = Red            4  4  DarkRed  
5 = Purple         5  5  DarkMagenta  
6 = Yellow         6  6  DarkYellow  
7 = White          7  7  Gray  
8 = Gray           8  8  DarkGray  
9 = Light Blue     9  9  Blue  
A = Light Green   10  a  Green  
B = Light Aqua    11  b  Cyan  
C = Light Red     12  c  Red  
D = Light Purple  13  d  Magenta  
E = Light Yellow  14  e  Yellow  
F = Bright White  15  f  White
```

And also PowerShell has two different ColorTable Entries:

```
ColorTable05    REG_DWORD    0x562401
ColorTable06    REG_DWORD    0xf0edee
```

The latter one being PowerShell's `DarkYellow` compared with CMD's `Yellow = 0x8080` explains the difference in your pictures.